# How to append character in long integer?

Tags: c#, long-integer

I want to append a character to a long integer, using the below code:

```
if (strArrIds[1].Contains("CO"))
{
    long rdb2 = Convert.ToInt64(strArrIds[1].Substring(strArrIds[1].Length - 1));
    assessmentEntity.RatingType = rdb2;
}
```

If `rdb2 = 5`, I want to append a `L` to this value, like `rdb2 = 5L`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: string mynewstring = "L" + rb2.ToString();

Comment: What is the datatype of "assessmentEntity.RatingType"?

Comment: assessmentEntity.RatingType data type is long

Comment: If so, you don't need to append an 'L' as you'd do with literal assignments. You append an 'L' only in a case like: long x=5L, but at run-time, you don't append an L. You either use Convert or Parse or TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `Long.Parse` instead Convert.ToInt64 to get the long and you wont need to append `L` to make it long

```
if (strArrIds[1].Contains("CO"))
{
    long rdb2 = long.Parse(strArrIds[1].Substring(strArrIds[1].Length - 1));
    assessmentEntity.RatingType = rdb2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing a lot of these, and if this item will be used for further processing, you could consider turning this into a class which might be easier to manage. This would also allow you to more easily customise your ratings.

I'm thinking maybe a factory might serve you well also which could instantiate and return your assessment entity. You could then leverage a dependency injection strategy for any other functionality.

Its a little hard to tell what you require this for without a bit more context.

If this is a once off, I would refactor to

```
assessmentEntity.RatingType = strArrIds[1].Contains("CO") ? 
          String.Concat(long.Parse(strArrIds[1].Substring(strArrIds[1].Length - 1)).ToString(), "L") :
          "0N";
```

Assuming "0N" is some other default rating..

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an `L` here. That is only for literals of type `long` appearing in the C# source.

You could do something like:

```
string str1 = strArrIds[1];
if (str1.Contains("CO"))
{
    long rdb2 = str1[str1.Length - 1] - '0';
    if (rdb2 < 0L || rdb2 > 9L)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected rdb2 value from str1=" + str1);
    assessmentEntity.RatingType = rdb2;
}
```